# Play Websocket connection closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.4

I am getting started with webSockets, angular & play. I use https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket for a nice angular integration. A connection as such:

```
var dataStream = $websocket('wss://echo.websocket.org/');
```

works great. However trying to connect to:

```
var dataStream = $websocket('wss://localhost:9000/socket');
```

Results in:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:9000/socket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

In the play / netty log I only find:

```
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
```

This is the code I use in the backend:

```
def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request => out =>
    MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
  }
object MyWebSocketActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new MyWebSocketActor(out))
}
class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      out ! ("I received your message: " + msg)
  }
}
```

(based on: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWebSockets)

Here my code:
https://github.com/dataplayground/playground/blob/master/public/javascripts/main.js

Comment: I'd like to comment on two things: 1. Have you tried using the normal ws protocol and not the secure one (wss). Like this `$websocket('ws://localhost:9000/socket')`. 2. You have defined an actor handling `[String, String]` but you are actually working with JSON in your Angular part. Both should actually match, so: `WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue]`

Comment: super. Thank you both your points are valid! This is the solution. Do you want to write a solution?

Comment: However I still do not receive a result in Angular - even though I send one like: `out ! (msg \ "foo")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:

1. Have you tried using the normal ws protocol and not the secure one (wss)? It should go like this: `$websocket('ws://localhost:9000/socket')`
2. You have defined an actor handling `[String, String]` but you are actually working with JSON in your Angular part. Both should actually match, so try: `WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue]`

I am not really sure that you are returning a proper JSON data, and also about the handling on your Angular side.

First if you use the backslash `\` method (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsValue) you get a `JsValue` but this does not necessarily represent a valid JSON. If you have `{"foo": "test"}` and search for **for** then you get "test" but this is not really a valid JSON.

Just so you get a fast feedback: try either changing the Websocket Actor to be of type `[JsValue, String]` OR you can just construct a new JsValue in your Actor:

```
class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: JsValue =>
      Logger.debug("actor something  " + out)
      Logger.debug("message  " + Json.prettyPrint(msg))

      val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""
      {
          "fooReply" : "Something"
      }
      """)
      out ! json
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Does this come from ng-websocket that you have to get the `data` property and not directly the `message`?

```
dataStream.onMessage(function (message) {
    collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
});
```

Comment: This comes directly from their tutorial: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket

Comment: Okay, I see. Is it working properly now with the correct JsValue object?

Comment: Thanks for asking. The problem stated in the question is solved. However as I am new to scala & play framework I have troubles building the correct JSON value.  Maybe you can help me there or point me to some great resources.

Comment: I will suggest starting with the Play Scala JSON documentation (https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson). If you have more specific problem, it would be good to open a new question so that we don't abuse the comment functionality here